# How to add editors to Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I noticed today that i don't have an `HTML` editor in my list. **How can i add it and others if need be?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the [Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) -- or EE Devlopers version of Eclipse, which includes the Web Tools Platform.

Other types of files are usually automatically loaded as text files. To get specific language capabilities you usually want to install a development library for that language into Eclipse. i.e. CDT for C++, PyDev for Python, etc..

Also you can find how to associate arbitrary file types to specific editors here :[Eclipse File Type Association](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/satinfo/v3r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sat.doc/concepts/cirerwp.htm).