# How to disable JBoss Tools editors in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, eclipse-plugin

I do have the problem that all my files are opened by default with a relevant JBoss Tools editor. Unfortunately they are slow on my machine and not always useful if I just want to edit a single tag in a XML file or so.

If possible I don't want to uninstall the JBoss Tools since it might be useful sometimes. But I want to open my files with a built-in editor by default.

**Here's my question:**
How to disable JBoss Tools editors and set built-in editors as my Eclipse's default editors? How to disable JBoss Tools editors for **content related file associations**?

Thank you. :-)

---

Kind of duplicated with:

- [How to add editors to Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800186/how-to-add-editors-to-eclipse)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the editor that will open a file per default in the

**Preferences->Editors->FileAssociations** menu.

Select one of the associated editors and press the **default** button.

EDIT: You can refine the file associations. To change the association for the `web.xml` file, got to the same file associations menu and click **add** in the upper right corner. Type `web.xml` and press **OK**, then edit the associated editors.

EDIT2:

Unfortunately, there is no setting for associating editors with content types directly. Content type menu is mainly for setting default encodings. The editor associations are relayed by the file associations.

You can associate file extensions or full file names with editors. Wildcards are restricted, so you cannot associate an editor with all `.x*ml` files.

If you are OK with making several changes, here are the exemplary steps to open all `.xhtml` files with the built-in web page editor (tried and working in my 3.7): in the file associations menu, click the `.xhtml` item, then select the editor of your choice in the list below and click on the **default** button on the right-hand side. From now on a double-click on an `.xhtml` file will open it in the built-in editor instead of the JBoss Tools.

Comment: But what's about content related file associations. `web.xml` is still opened by JBoss Tools.

Comment: @Zubi - have added more details for association refinement

Comment: Danke. But this only allows me to define a specific file name. Unfortunately my `xhtml` file will be still opened by an JBoss Tools editor.

Comment: @Zubi - Unfortunately, there is no way to do this your way. See second edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "source" tab as the default, when opening xhtml files.

Preferences -> JBoss Tools -> Web -> Editors

Mark only the "Use source tab as default"  option.